# question about stereographic projection

Tags: general-topology, stereographic-projections

Suppose that $S^1 = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2|x^2+y^2=1\}$, and let $x \in S^1$. How can I go about finding a homeomorphism from $S^1 \to S^1$ that sends $x$ to $(0,1)$. I thought about defining the line from $x$ to $p$ as $l(t) = tx+1$. But I'm unsure what to do. I just want a hint , and not the answer to this question.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you familiar with complex numbers?

Comment: yes I am familiar with complex numbers.

Comment: Maybe consider a mapping $x \mapsto (0,1)$ that is continuous, using the complex numbers. An alternative is to use linear algebra; they're the same thing, when considering these kinds of transformations.

Comment: what do you mean by using linear algebra? I'm not sure I see what you're saying with that

Comment: Do you mean $x \in S^1$? If so, it is confusing because in the definition of $S^1$ the same symbol is used for something else. And what is $p$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(x,y) \in S^1$ we can find such a homeomorphism by a rotation of the plane (restricted to $S^1$), in essence a multiplication by $e^{i\phi}$ for a suitable $\phi$, looking at the plane as $\Bbb C$, or the linear map with matrix $\begin{bmatrix} \cos \phi & -\sin \phi \\ \sin \phi & \cos \phi\end{bmatrix}$ etc.

This has in itself nothing to do with a stereographic projection. You can rotate any point of the circle onto any other one.